# exec-shield kernel parameter cant be enabled in arm platform

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, buffer-overflow, sysctl, kbuild

i want to enable kernel.exec-shield parameter in an embedded platform at run-time or compile time. i have 32-bit arm architecture in my embedded platform. i list all the kernel parameters with following command.

```
sysctl -a
```

and i get many unrelated parameters but kernel.exec-shield is not listed.

i also cant find any related parameter in kconfig environment with menuconfig.

i want to counter buffer overflow vulnerabilities like described below.

http://people.redhat.com/mingo/exec-shield/

How can i do that in arm architecture?

regards...

Comment: What distribution are you running? exec-shield is : 1. old and superseded by PAX and 2. Redhat-specific. On Debian derivatives you can use NX.

Comment: i want to add exec-shield in my arm based embedded linux platform. Response of "uname -r" is 3.14.28-1.6 in my system. There are some functions in bootloader that modifies xn (execute never) bit. But i think exec-shield is not just "buffer overflow protection". According to wiki it contains some other features such as address space randomization, pie etc